# SOAP UI variables (e.g., date)

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui

I am using SOAP UI Pro.  I have a request from which this is an excerpt:

```
               <ns2:OfficeType>
                   <ns2:OfficeTypeCode>M</ns2:OfficeTypeCode>
                   <ns2:EffectiveDate>2000-01-01</ns2:EffectiveDate>
                   <ns2:TerminationDate>9999-12-31</ns2:TerminationDate>
                   <ns2:IsPrimary>true</ns2:IsPrimary>
                </ns2:OfficeType>
```

Instead of for instance, 2000-01-01, I want to use today (so for the day I am writing this it would be 2015-03-10.  You may be reading on March 12 in which case it would be 2015-03-12, etc.).  I could theoretically edit the SOAP request each time I send it out and replace the fields with the current date, but this is supposed to be automatic.  I would like a say to say, instead of 2010-01-01 use something like $(Today'YYYY-MM-DD')  (that is just an example probably nothing near the actual syntax).

Is there a way to get the current date placed into a SOAP UI message from SOAP UI Pro?

Answer (score 7):

In SOAPUI you can use groovy code directly in your SOAP Request using the follow notation `${=groovy expression}`, so in your case you can use `${=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new java.util.Date())}` to get today date in `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

Directly in your test request you can use:

```
<ns2:OfficeType>
    <ns2:OfficeTypeCode>M</ns2:OfficeTypeCode>
    <ns2:EffectiveDate>${=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new java.util.Date())}</ns2:EffectiveDate>
    <ns2:TerminationDate>9999-12-31</ns2:TerminationDate>
    <ns2:IsPrimary>true</ns2:IsPrimary>
</ns2:OfficeType>
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: nice solution, +1 for groovy expression

Comment: Could shorten it to `String.format("%tF", new Date())`, but good on ya!

Comment: @SiKing ohhh thanks guys `:)`, also for `String.format`!

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a nice UTC formated date/time:

```
<ns2:EffectiveDate>${=java.time.Instant.now().truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.SECONDS)}</ns2:EffectiveDate>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SoapUI Pro, then you may have the following script in *TestRunListener.beforeRun* **Event**

```html
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
def today = new Date()
def dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
def date = dateFormat.format(today)
log.info date
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue('DATE', date)
```

And in the request have

`<ns2:EffectiveDate>${#TestCase#DATE}</ns2:EffectiveDate>`
i.e., using the value `DATE` which was set in the beforeRun event.

Note: You can change the date format whatever you want, here it is used `yyyy-MM-dd` format as you mentioned in the question.